# ElasticMapReduce streaming compressed output

Tags: hadoop, boto, amazon-emr

I'm running streaming jobs,  with python scripts for the map and reduce.  The job flow I create with the boto library.

I'm using gzip input files.  How can I create gzip output files,  though?

Answer (score 0):

I use java to process gzip files and generate output in gzip compression. I use below code

```
    FileOutputFormat.setCompressOutput(job, true);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputCompressorClass(job, GzipCodec.class);  
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, output path));
```

I hope You will find similar API/ code in python.

You can generate gzip files as your generated output. Pass '-D mapred.output.compress=true -D mapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec' as option to your streaming job.